# Login Example with nodejs and jsonwebtoken: can't read the token verification result

Tags: node.js, json-web-token

My MIDDLEWARE checks if the tokens provided by users are correct.
The secuirity control, implemented by using jsonwebtoken, was inside the middleware and it was working fine.
After I decided to move all this security checks in another file: TokenManger.js

But I don't know how to set the code between the two files.
I tried many ways but no one is working.

So just for a better understanding I paste in the following an example code, which is not working. This is about the middleware:

```
...
router.use(function(req,res,next){
        var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
        //decode token
        if(token){
            TokenManager.verifyToken(token,true,function(err,key){
                if(err) return res.json({ success : false, message : "Failed to authenticate token"});
                else next();
            });
        }else{
            // no token, return error
            return res.status(403).send({
                success : false,
                message: 'No token provided!'
            });
        }
});
...
```

In the other hand this is an example (and not working) implementation of the TokenManager.js:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('../../config.js');

var TokenManager = { 
    createToken: function(user) {
        if(user.admin){
            var token = jwt.sign(user, config.SECRET_WORD.ADMIN,{expiresIn:config.EXPIRE_TIME.ADMIN_TOKEN});
        }else{
            var token = jwt.sign(user, config.SECRET_WORD.USER,{expiresIn:config.EXPIRE_TIME.USER_TOKEN});  
        }
        return token;
    },
    verifyToken: function(token, admin, decode){
        if(admin){
            //admin authentication
            jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.ADMIN, function(err,key){
                if(err){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }else{
            //user authentication
            jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.USER, function(err,key){
                if(err){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

module["exports"] = TokenManager;
```

Actually the `createToken(user)` function is working fine with the previous code, there is a problems only with the `verifyToken(token, admin, decode)` function. But I care about the design so if you have suggestions about the creation too, they are more than welcome.

Just to complete the picture, this is how I call the `createToken(user)` function:

```
...
.post(function(req,res){
        User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err,user){
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found!' });
            }else{
                if(user.password != req.body.password){
                    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password!' });
                }else{
                    //token creation
                    var token = TokenManager.createToken(user);
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: token
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
...
```

Comment: You are passing callback to `verifyToken`, but there is not callback in the signature of `verifyToken`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `function(err, key)` to `verifyToken`, but there is not `callback` in the signature of verifyToken.

Try changing the `verifyToken` function to

```
verifyToken: function(token, admin, callback){
    if(admin){
        //admin authentication
        jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.ADMIN, callback);
    }else{
        //user authentication
        jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.USER, callback);
    }
}
```

**Update** : Without callback

```
verifyToken: function(token, admin){
    try {
       if(admin){
          //admin authentication
          jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.ADMIN, callback);
       }else{
          //user authentication
          jwt.verify(token, config.SECRET_WORD.USER, callback);
       }
       return true;
    } catch(err)
       return false;
    }   
}
```

And use like this in your middleware:

```
if (TokenManager.verifyToken(token,true)){
    return next();
} else {
    return res.json({ success : false, message : "Failed to authenticate token"});
}
```

Comment: Are you able to make the veryToken function working also without a callback? should be the asyn way?

Comment: Yes, we can make `verifyToken` working without callback. But, without `async` or `callback`, it will throw error that you have to catch. Explained here https://stormpath.com/blog/nodejs-jwt-create-verify#how-to-verify-jwts Check my updated answer.